# Back button with multiple (2) webviews

Tags: android, button, webview, back

I am playing with an ap that has 2 webviews set up within a `tabhost/tabwidget` layout, my problem is that i don't know how to make them navigate back through page history, at least for both of them. I ca do it for the first webview (`webview1`) but i don't know how to do it for the second one in my second tab.

Comment: If I simplify the problem to 1 webview/activity, what you want is to have back button functionality when you interact inside the webview?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient but you might still be stuck on it, or someone else might be. Use the code below, it works for me using tabHost. webView1 and webView2 being your two webviews.
Add it above the onCreate bundle.

```
public void onBackPressed(){

if (webView1.isFocused() && webView1.canGoBack()) {
    webView1.goBack();       
}
else {
    //Add something you want to do, or leave blank to do nothing.
}

if (webView2.isFocused() && webView2.canGoBack()) {
    webView2.goBack();       
}
else {
    //Add something you want to do, or leave blank to do nothing.
}
}
```